# Trying to understand the concept of "resource pooling" in cloud computing in depth

Tags: cloud

So basically, every post, article, explanation I've read pretty much said the below.

"Resource pooling is an IT term used in cloud computing environments to describe a situation in which providers serve multiple clients, customers or "tenants" with provisional and scalable services."

so my question is,

1. Is this concept somehow similar to a "car pool" or is it a different concept?
2. According to the definition/explanation, resource pooling just means serving many clients/customers scalable services.. why is it called resource "pooling" then? Doesn't pooling mean everyone chipping in some money or resources and then combining all those individual contributions into one big sum?
3. What makes resource pooling more desirable or better than non resource pooling services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is similar in the sense that many customers ("cloud service users"/"persons not owning the car") use the same service ("cloud service"/"car drive") from a provider ("cloud service provider"/"car driver -usually infrastructure owner/car owner-") at the same time for a fee/fare, that the total cost -economic and environmental- is reduced, and that the resources ("hardware, cable, virtual machines, etc."/"seats, gas, horse power, etc.") are distributed between the customers, and that the ones who want more of the service ("use more virtual machine power"/"they are driven further") pay more, proportionally.
2. Following your definition, it is called "pooling" because the provider acts as the common stock and manager of it, which is maintained with money paid by the customers and which supplies shared resources to the customers.
3. From the client's point of view, it is more desirable because it is cheaper, and also more manageable and reliable (virtualization adds a layer of abstraction that provides great flexibility and security). From the environment's point of view, it is better also because it produces less contamination/destruction than if the customers had set their own infrastructure and services.